# parliament: trouble starting the parliament triplestore server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rdf, glibc, triplestore, parliament

I downloaded [ParliamentQuickStart-v2.7.6-gcc-64](http://semwebcentral.org/frs/?group_id=159)`` for my Ubuntu 12.04.

Unfortunatly, I ran through the following Exception (see below) when trying to start Paliament with the command

```
./StartParliament.sh
```

Obviously the tomcat server is not running proprely

```
localhost:8080 responses HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND


Using the following version of Java:
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~precise1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in  [jar:file:/home/leonzo/opt/parliament/lib/slf4j-log4j12-  1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_parliament.war__parliament__.8k5u9b/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2015-02-24 14:22:47,146 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.servlet.ParliamentServlet] Initializing parliament servlet
2015-02-24 14:22:47,600 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.ParliamentBridgeConfiguration] Initializing com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.configuration.IndexProcessorConfigurationHandler
2015-02-24 14:22:47,600 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.configuration.IndexProcessorConfigurationHandler] Loading com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.index.temporal.TemporalIndexFactory
2015-02-24 14:22:47,626 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.configuration.IndexProcessorConfigurationHandler] Loading com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.index.spatial.SpatialIndexFactory
2015-02-24 14:22:47,646 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.graph.ModelManager] Loading Model
2015-02-24 14:22:47,646 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.graph.ModelManager] Loading Parliament configuration with working directory "/home/leonzo/opt/parliament/."
2015-02-24 14:22:47,659 [main] WARN  [org.mortbay.log] failed ParliamentServlet: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/leonzo/opt/parliament/bin/libParliament.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./bin/libdb-5.3.so)
2015-02-24 14:22:47,660 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.servlet.BulkServlet] -------- BulkServlet
2015-02-24 14:22:47,660 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.servlet.BulkServlet] Initializing BulkServlet
2015-02-24 14:22:47,661 [main] ERROR [/parliament] unavailable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ParliamentBridge class has not been initialized yet
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.ParliamentBridge.getInstance(ParliamentBridge.java:36)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.servlet.BulkServlet.init(BulkServlet.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.jetty.JettyServerCore.start(JettyServerCore.java:114)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.jetty.CmdLineJettyServer.main(CmdLineJettyServer.java:22)
 2015-02-24 14:22:47,664 [main] WARN  [org.mortbay.log] failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@15afba6a{/parliament,file:/home/leonzo/opt/parliament/webapps/parliament.war}: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/leonzo/opt/parliament/bin/libParliament.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./bin/libdb-5.3.so)
2015-02-24 14:22:47,665 [main] WARN  [org.mortbay.log] failed ContextHandlerCollection@43f79045: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/leonzo/opt/parliament/bin/libParliament.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./bin/libdb-5.3.so)
2015-02-24 14:22:47,667 [main] WARN  [org.mortbay.log] failed HandlerCollection@610994db: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/leonzo/opt/parliament/bin/libParliament.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./bin/libdb-5.3.so)
2015-02-24 14:22:47,667 [main] ERROR [org.mortbay.log] Error starting handlers
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/leonzo/opt/parliament/bin/libParliament.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./bin/libdb-5.3.so)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jni.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:184)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.KbGraphFactory.getKbConfigForDefaultGraph(KbGraphFactory.java:75)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph(KbGraphFactory.java:31)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.graph.ModelManager.initialize(ModelManager.java:290)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.ParliamentBridge.<init>(ParliamentBridge.java:68)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.ParliamentBridge.initialize(ParliamentBridge.java:53)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.joseki.bridge.servlet.ParliamentServlet.init(ParliamentServlet.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.jetty.JettyServerCore.start(JettyServerCore.java:114)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.jetty.CmdLineJettyServer.main(CmdLineJettyServer.java:22)
2015-02-24 14:22:47,676 [main] INFO  [com.bbn.parliament.jena.jetty.JettyServerCore] Starting Parliament server
```

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` and `ldd --version`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specifically a programming question. The problem, according to your error output, is that a specific version of `glibc` is not found (`>=2.17`). This is likely because your operating system, 12.04, is quite old, and shipped with an older version of `glibc`.

There are three choices available to you.

**1.** Update `glibc` to a version high enough. This may cause problems with your system because most of the apps installed are going to be relying on a previous version of `glibc`, so I would try this in a VM first. You may need a compiler on your server to do this.

**2.** Upgrade your system to a more recent version of Ubuntu. This is probably not an option for you, since you are likely running this on a server and using the LTS release for that reason. However, if you can upgrade, 14.04.2 is the most recent LTS release and has a sufficiently recent version of `glibc`.

**3.** The specific component that is failing is `libdb-5.3`. Compile that for 12.04 with your current version of `glibc` and replace the library in the `bin/` path of your application server.

Before doing any of these steps, make sure your system is fully upgraded with the latest patches for 12.04 (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`).